# Append and print content of Excel files from Sharepoint into an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, automation

but want to use Python more.

I would like to build a Python script which will use my credentials to log into Sharepoint, follow a path to a named folder and every of its subfolders, identify file modified date in each subfolder which is equal to yesterday's date, append all the data of a specific tab from each excel file and print onto a consolidated excel file with each appended row, including the file name in one column, the folder path in one column and the file modified date(which should always be yesterday's date).

This will be a repeated process for different named folders and subfolders, and with a scheduled script running time, to print the consolidated/appended excel file into a folder on sharepoint daily.